# PHP Array with multiple lines

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the example below. How to I get only the value in the first line (the audio file path)? I have already tried `array_rand()` which only gives me values letter by letter. Sorry if this has been answered before, couldn't find anything myself. Thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
[0] => path/to/audiofile.mp3
3500440
audio/mpeg

[1] => path/to/anotheraudiofile.mp3
5661582
audio/mpeg

...
)
```

Edit: var_dump gives me this:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(98) "path/to/audiofile.mp3
3500440
audio/mpeg
"
[1]=>
string(95) "path/to/anotheraudiofile.mp3
5661582
audio/mpeg
"
```

}

Comment: Please make a `var_dump`, not a `print_r`

Comment: What do you mean by _"I only get the value in the first line"_? Do you mean that `$array[0]` only returns the first line, or you only _see_ the first line? What system are you running this code on (windows, Linux, OSX or *NIX)? what does `strlen` tell you? More info would be nice

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: $array[0] returns everything at the moment, I only need the first line. Running on windows. I would have given you more info if I weren't so lost. Will look into the other stuff.

Comment: so whats array_rand() doing in there?

Comment: Where do you get these values from. Are these newline characters between the lines? Or `<br>` HTML code?

Comment: @HerrSerker This is how Wordpress stores audio files that have been attached to posts. I can dump the full array here as well, if that helps. I'm trying to get a list of audio files that have been attached to a Wordpress post and unfortunately the array doesn't store the file paths separately but with file size and mimetype as well. I'm still a little bit new with this, so this is the first time I'm coming across an array with more than one value stored to one key within it. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question or looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Look at EliasVanOotegems answer. You need to split the single array values by using the explode function of php. Check the function description in http://php.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to split on line return ?

```
$tmp = explode(PHP_EOL, $myArray[0]);
$tmp = explode('"', $tmp[0]);
$path = $tmp[1];
```

Comment: use double quotes on the newline

Comment: This worked, but I had to correct around. Double quotes on newline just like @Ghost said. '\n' doesn't work. Also `$` on the variables within the `explode()` function. Thanks!

Comment: @charlenemasters: Please, don't hard-code the end of line character. PHP has a pre-defined constant `PHP_EOL` that holds the correct end of line character for the system that it's running on. If your server is running windows, `PHP_EOL` will be `\r\n`. For other systems, `PHP_EOL` will be `\n`. Using that constant makes your code more portable

Answer (score 2):

The real solution would be to alter the code that is actually constructing this array, however, you can easily extract what you need with a couple array function (of which there are many):

```
$array[0] = explode(PHP_EOL, $array[0]);//PHP_EOL is the new-line character
echo $array[0][0];//get the first line
```

You can process the entire array like so:

```
function extractFirstLine($val)
{
    $val = explode(PHP_EOL, $val);
    return $val[0];
}
$array = array_map('extractFirstLine', $array);
```

Or, since PHP 5.3 the more common approach:

```
$array = array_map(function($v)
{
    $v = explode(PHP_EOL, $v);
    return $v[0];
}, $array);
```

And since PHP 5.4, you can write this even shorter:

```
$array = array_map(function($v)
{
    return (explode(PHP_EOL, $v))[0];
}, $array);
```

That ought to do it (Note, this code is untested, but the man pages should help you out if something isn't quite right).

Answer (score 0):

B"e aware of it depends on the os Line maybe diffrent character, you may use \r\n if you using a win os
$Path = substr($array[0] , 0 , strpos("\n",$array[0]))

Comment: ***OR*** use the platform dependant, predefined runtime constant `PHP_EOL`, which will be `\r\n` on a windows system, and `\n` on Linux

Comment: Yes I wasn't have any knowledge about this constant.